# Subset of a Pandas Dataframe consisting of rows with specific column values

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I'm having a problem with a single line of my code.
Here is what I'd like to achieve:

- reading_now is a string consisting of 3 characters
- df2 is a data frame that is a subset of df1
- I'd like df2 to consist of rows from df1 where the first three characters of the value in column "Code" is equal to "reading_now"

I tried using the following two lines with no success:

```
*df2 = df1.loc[(df1['Code'])[0:3] == reading_now]*
*df2 = df1[(str(df1.Code)[0:3] == reading_now)]*
```

Comment: Can you provide a example of the string and the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you were really close with your 2nd attempt.

You could solve this a couple of different ways.

```
reading_now = 'AAA'
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'Code': 'AAA'}, {'Code': 'BBB'}, {'Code': 'CCC'}])
```

**solution**:

`df2 = df1[df1['Code'].str.startswith(reading_now)]`

or

`df2 = df1[df1['Code'][0:3] == reading_now]`

The `df2` dataframe will contain the row that starts with the `reading_now` string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
df2 = df1[df1['Code'].str[0:3] == reading_now]
```

For example:

```
data = ['abcd', 'cbdz', 'abcz', 'bdaz']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Code'])
df2 = df1[df1['Code'].str[0:3] == 'abc']
```

df2 will result in a dataframe with 'Code' column containing 'abcd' and 'abcz'